# How can I check that I have the correct Delphi XE2 update?

Tags: delphi, installation, delphi-xe2

Yesterday I installed Delphi XE2 using the download option, so I guess the installed files came from Embarcadero up to date as 1st Nov. I assume that I therefore acquired Update 1 (the one that otherwise needed a complete reinstall?). To check, clicking 'Check for updates' in the program group produces 'No updates available', yet Help About shows only 'Help Release 1 for Delphi XE2....' in 'Installed Updates'.

I now see a link to Marco Cantu's site at http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/delphi_xe2_update2.html which talks about an update 2 (but you have to have update 1 already in place).

Can anyone comment on the installation that I have? I dont want to continue installing libraries if I've got to reinstall it again.

Comment: One of my machines had minor problems with the patch update from update 1 to update 2. To make it fly I had to download the ISO for update 2 and do the who lot. That worked very well indeed and I didn't need to explicitly uninstall the earlier version. It also gets the help update installed too. But from where you are with not having update 1 in place then I think you need the full ISO.

Comment: Thanks David. If installing from the full ISO does it retain any settings, eg component libraries?

Comment: Yes it seems to do a great job of leaving all your settings intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can uninstall XE2 and then install XE2 with Update #2 from the new ISO (available for registered users only, I'm afraid).

See also http://www.bobswart.nl/weblog/Blog.aspx?RootId=5:5014

Comment: Yes, I've just seen your excellent summary of the state-of-affairs at http://www.delphifeeds.com/go/f/85904?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+delphifeeds+%28DelphiFeeds.com%29 Thanks Bob.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot just go from XE2 to update 2 directly.
Update 1 is a **mandatory** install which requires you to first completely uninstall.  Then reinstall.  All subsequent delphi xe2 updates will then install without an uninstall first.
Refer delphi xe2 update 1 release notes as per links provided in above answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have update 1 otherwise in Help / About, 'Installed Updates' you have 2 items:
'RAD Studio XE2 Delphi and C++ Builder UPdate 1' and the one you see 'Help Release ...'

[Edit]: Information over update 1: [Here](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/delphi_xe2_update1.html) (Marco Cantu) and [here](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41650) (Embarcadero)

Comment: Thanks Arjen, but why would 'Check for Updates' simply say 'No updates available' then? Was Update 1 some kind of special update then?

Comment: Yes it was a special update, code from GLScene was accidentally used: http://delphitools.info/2011/09/05/glscene-source-code-used-in-firemonkey/ 
Update 1 is a actually a reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the version number in the About box.

- Delphi XE2: 16.0.4256.43595
- XE2 Update 1: 16.0.4276.44006
- XE2 Update 2: 16.0.4316.44803
- XE2 Update 3: 16.0.4358.45540
- XE2 Update 4: 16.0.4429.46931